# Why am I unable to create a new Java project in Intellij using both the Maven Plugin and the Google App Engine Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

**Would somebody be able to explain why I am unable to create a new Java project in Intellij using both the Maven Plugin and the Google App Engine Plugin?** I had previously created a Google App Engine project in Intellij and it was very easy to build and deploy my app using the App Engine plugin. Now I'm building my second app, and I would like to incorporate Maven as well but they seem to be mutually exclusive. I have seen that there are Maven archetypes for Google App Engine, but I am unsure of how to import those archetypes, or what their purpose is.

Comment: Copy and adjust your pom.xml. Put the pom.xml into a directory where your project will be (Or even better: Create a new pom.xml from the archetypes). In IntelliJ go to `File`, `Open` and select your pom.xml. It will load dependencies and everything for a while. Once it is done it should automatically detect that it's an app engine project and will add a couple of build targets for debugging and deploying. At least that how it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you konqi. I ended up using a very similar strategy to what you suggested. I used the first 9 steps from this [Google App Engine Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/hello_world) to build a maven project from an appengine archetype in terminal. Then I opened intellij and imported the project (using all default values) and intellij automatically detected the appengine dependency.